# Microservice not registering with Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I have just followed the following article https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring
but I cant get my micro service to register with eureka.

customer-service.yml

```
# Spring properties
spring:
  application:
     name: customer-service
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: 192.168.99.100
      port: 32768
      uri: mongodb://192.168.99.100:32768
      database: customer
      repositories:
        enabled: true

# Discovery Server Access
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:1111/eureka/

# HTTP Server
server:
  port: 2222   # HTTP (Tomcat) port
```

build.gradle for customer-service

```
group 'com.company'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.9.2.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

CustomerService.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@RestController
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    List<Customer> get() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    void post(@RequestBody @Valid Customer customer, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        repository.save(customer);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Will configure using accounts-server.yml
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "customer-service");

        SpringApplication.run(CustomerService.class, args);
    }
}
```

registration-server.yml

```
# Configure this Discovery Server
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: 127.0.0.1
  client:  # Not a client, don't register with yourself
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/

server:
  port: 1111   # HTTP (Tomcat) port
```

Comment: There is nothing cloud related in your gradle file... So no eurake client jars, no registration.

Comment: I have added the following dependency but still no luck  compile 'com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:1.4.11'

Comment: You are following a tutorial, then follow the tutorial... Add the spring cloud eureka dependency as also explained in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who might be having the same issue, build.gradle on the service should look like the one below.

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'


sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Brixton.RELEASE'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka')
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.9.2.RELEASE'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```